# SWT Nebula CDateTime DateSelection

Tags: java, swt, nebula

I want to use the Nebula CDateTime component, but I have the problem, that the selected date is not marked in the panel (selected is the 17):

[image]

What do I need to change so that the selected date ishighlighted?

Comment: Please show the snippet of code where you create the `CDateTime`. Ideally, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug report about this:

[Highlighting feature for `CDateTime`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=302960). There's also code that you could use to get it working in your code.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to ever have made it into the release version for whatever reason.